# Access Typescript class method or attribute from inner function of another method

Tags: typescript, angular

Basically the title already explains the problem. I have attached a code extract, which should put my idea across.

```
export class MyComponent {

  constructor(private element: ElementRef, private myservice:MyService){}

  onChange(event: any): void {
    // works fine
    var imageElem = this.element.nativeElement.querySelector('.image');
    reader.onloadend = function() {
      // works fine
      console.log(imageElem)
      // does not work
      this.doSome(src);
      // does not work
      this.myservice.doSome();
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }

  doSome(src:string) {}
}
```

Comment: What is `reader`? What is `src`? What is `file`?

Comment: Doesn't matter for question.

Comment: Well, your problem is "does not work", without any further details. And the first immediate problems is that the code uses undefined variables, so...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would leverage [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for the `onloadend` like:

```
reader.onloadend = () => {
  ...   
}
```

This way `this` will be instance of `MyComponent` inside callback because:

> arrow functions capture the this value of the enclosing context

Comment: Thank you very much. By the way this.reader.onloadend = function() {...} does not work.